# Switch view with a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

When I rund my application I can choose which view to show in my viewFlipper by running:

```
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
```

in onCreate, I can switch the view in my onClick()

```
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
```

When I want to switch child from my code (not in my main app) i get the following problem!

```
02-02 12:17:08.620: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1005): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only call `setDisplayedChild()` from the main application thread, not from a background thread.

Comment: Sure, but how can I do that? I need to call if from my other thread, which has no access to the GUI thread.

Comment: @Petter: Use a `Handler`. Or, call `post()` on the `ViewFlipper`. Or, use `runOnUiThread()`.